# How to get permutations with odd transpositions?

Tags: c#

I have an algorithm with all possible permutations, can i get permutations with only odd transpositions. Or simplify the algorithm to find only such permutations. For example, array {1,2,3,4}. If I move one element I will get only one transposition, and it odd tansposition: {2,1,3,4}, {3,2,1,4}, {4,2,3,1}, {1,3,2,4}, {1,4,3,2}, {1,2,4,3}.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            ShowAllCombinations(arr);
            Console.Read();
        }
        public static void ShowAllCombinations<T>(IList<T> arr, string current = "")
        {
            if (arr.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(current);
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++) 
            {
                List<T> lst = new List<T>(arr);
                lst.RemoveAt(i);
                ShowAllCombinations(lst, current + arr[i].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

This algorithm gives all permutations, but not only odd ones.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ShowAllCombinations` method is inconvenient, the string should stay a list so you can process the elements.

Once you have a complete list of elements, you can "unpermute" back to the natural order and count the number of swaps. This assumes unique elements (no repetitions) and that the list is one-based. Note that this method permutes the list, will want to create a copy somewhere.

```
public void SwapCount(List<int> arr)
{
    var swapCount = 0;

    // double for loop, compare the value at the outer position
    // to the value at the inner position.
    for (var i=0; i<arr.Count; i++)
    {
        // Start at the index after the outer loop
        for (var j=i+1; j<arr.Count; j++)
        {
            // If the inner value is what the outer value
            // is supposed to be then swap it.
            if (arr[j] == i+1)
            {
                var t = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = t;
                swapCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine($"swap count: {swapCount}");
}
```

output

```
> SwapCount(new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 })
swap count: 0
> SwapCount(new List<int>() { 2, 1, 3, 4 })
swap count: 1
> SwapCount(new List<int>() { 1, 3, 2, 4 })
swap count: 1
> SwapCount(new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4, 2})
swap count: 2
>
```

---

This is ~ O(n^2), but I'm assuming performance is not so important here. You can find more efficient algorithms here: [Parity of permutation with parallelism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63207663/1462295)

Comment: imho this is a key to understand what do you want to get: "A permutation is called odd if it can be expressed as a product of odd number of transpositions."